# Stylesheet alternative for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

- In web applications we can define an external stylesheet(CSS) to maintain
  the consistency and the standard of the user interface design, but in Java swing
  applications How would I obtain it? How to write such style classes in swing?
- Here I'm not asking about look and feels but setting up basic presets,
  like button width, height. Header and font presets like we do in css by defining classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would subclass some of the main components with defaults most likely. Though I would highly recommend staying away from Swing if at all possible as its basically deprecated at this point.

```
public class MyButton extends JButton {
    public MyButton() {
         super();
         setSize(....);
         setFont(...);
         //other default stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you recommending any other alternative instead of swing for windows/desktop based applications?

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra I had assumed you were doing web based work since you mentioned CSS. I have no experience doing Java desktop applications so I cannot speak to that at all in fact. Sorry about the confusion. Although I do believe Eclipse has something that it uses, but I forget the name.